# Grouping the immediate nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am using the XSLT 1.0 version and I have the below XML to transform,

```html
<Root>
 <Child No="1" Month="0" Date="13/08/2014" Payment="100">
  <Totals amount="100"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="2" Month="1" Date="13/09/2014" Payment="100">
  <Totals amount="100"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="3" Month="2" Date="13/10/2014" Payment="200">
  <Totals amount="200"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="4" Month="3" Date="13/11/2014" Payment="300">
  <Totals amount="300"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="5" Month="4" Date="13/12/2014" Payment="300">
  <Totals amount="300"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="6" Month="5" Date="13/01/2015" Payment="100">
  <Totals amount="100"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="7" Month="6" Date="13/01/2015" Payment="100">
  <Totals amount="100"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="8" Month="7" Date="13/01/2015" Payment="100">
  <Totals amount="100"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="9" Month="8" Date="13/01/2015" Payment="100">
  <Totals amount="100"/>
 </Child>
 <Child No="10" Month="9" Date="13/01/2015" Payment="100">
  <Totals amount="100"/>
 </Child>
</Root>
```

I wanted to transform The XML as

```html
<PPS>
 <PP>
  <Ps>
   <StartMonth>0</StartMonth>
   <EndMonth>1</EndMonth>
   <P>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <startP>1</startP>
   </P>
   <P>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <startP>2</startP>
   </P>
  </Ps>
 </PP>
 <PP>
  <Ps>
   <StartMonth>2</StartMonth>
   <EndMonth>2</EndMonth>
   <P>
    <Amount>200</Amount>
    <startP>3</startP>
   </P>
  </Ps>
 </PP>
 <PP>
  <Ps>
   <StartMonth>3</StartMonth>
   <EndMonth>4</EndMonth>
   <P>
    <Amount>300</Amount>
    <startP>4</startP>
   </P>
   <P>
    <Amount>300</Amount>
    <startP>5</startP>
   </P>
  </Ps>
 </PP>
 <PP>
  <Ps>
   <StartMonth>5</StartMonth>
   <EndMonth>9</EndMonth>
   <P>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <startP>6</startP>
   </P>
   <P>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <startP>7</startP>
   </P>
   <P>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <startP>8</startP>
   </P>
   <P>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <startP>9</startP>
   </P>
   <P>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <startP>10</startP>
   </P>
  </Ps>
 </PP>
</PPS>
```

every time I wanted to create a "P" differing from the last Payment.
Here is the pseudo code, create a new PP, when child[n]/Payment <> child[n-1]/Payment.
P.S., I do not want to consider the Totals node even it has some values.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT. It wouldn't have been so long if it was in XSLT2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <PPS>
        <xsl:for-each select="Child">
            <xsl:variable name="Payment" select="@Payment"/>
            <xsl:variable name="start-end">
                <StartMonth>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Month"/>
                </StartMonth>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][self::Child and @Payment = $Payment]">
                        <EndMonth>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="month">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Payment" select="$Payment"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </EndMonth>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <EndMonth>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Month"/>
                        </EndMonth>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::Child and @Payment = $Payment])">
                <PP>
                    <Ps>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$start-end"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::Child and @Payment = $Payment]">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Payment" select="$Payment"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </Ps>
                </PP>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </PPS>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Child">
    <xsl:param name="Payment"/>
    <P>
        <Amount>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Payment"/>
        </Amount>
        <startP>
            <xsl:value-of select="@No"/>
        </startP>
    </P>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::Child and @Payment = $Payment]">
        <xsl:with-param name="Payment" select="$Payment"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Child" mode="month">
    <xsl:param name="Payment"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][self::Child and @Payment = $Payment]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="month">
                <xsl:with-param name="Payment" select="$Payment"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Month"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```